# Stripe API and Excel VBA - syntax for HTTP Post request

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a customer in Stripe using Excel VBA and the Stripe API. I'm able to do this successfully, however I've hit a snag.

When I send the following URL to the API, I am successfully creating a customer with the following parameters (auto_advance, collection_method, customer) set.
b_url + "/v1/invoices?auto_advance=false;collection_method=charge_automatically;customer=" + customerid

However, I am struggling on the syntax required in my URL when attempting to send values to a parameter with child attributes. Stripe customer object has a parameter called "custom_fields" that I would like to populate. The param requires a custom_fields.name and custom_fields.value.

How do I send parameters with a "dot"?[image]

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out the URL needs to be formatted as an array value to pass these. So sending

```
 ;custom_fields[0][name]=Provider;custom_fields[0][value]=TestName
```

worked great.